# Reading a GCS file using standalone on premise spark java program

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to read a file stored on GCS bucket using on premise standalone spark job in java. I have configured `SparkContext` with all necessary spark configuration. I am getting following error:

```
    at com.vr.HadoopSample.main(HadoopSample.java:78)
java.io.IOException: Error getting access token from metadata server at: http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromMetadataServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:208)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialConfiguration.getCredential(CredentialConfiguration.java:70)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1825)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1012)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:975)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2811)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2848)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2830)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:322)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:250)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2087)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:918)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:916)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:351)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.vr.HadoopSample.main(HadoopSample.java:78)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: metadata
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:972)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory$ComputeCredentialWithRetry.executeRefreshToken(CredentialFactory.java:158)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredentialFromMetadataServiceAccount(CredentialFactory.java:206)
    ... 33 more
17/10/10 11:34:24 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/10/10 11:34:24 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://169.254.189.252:4040
17/10/10 11:34:24 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
17/10/10 11:34:24 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

I have configured SparkConf using below properties:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.impl</name>
  <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.project.id</name>
  <value>your-ascii-google-project-id</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.system.bucket</name>
  <value>some-bucket-your-project-owns</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.working.dir</name>
  <value>/</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.auth.service.account.email</name>
  <value>your-service-account-email@developer.gserviceaccount.com</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>fs.gs.auth.service.account.keyfile</name>
  <value>/path/to/hadoop/conf/gcskey.p12</value>
</property>
```

I have followed instructions using Google Cloud Storage connector. I have not installed Spark on my machine but have used all its libraries in eclipse. Any Help would be greatly appreciated. I am not able to move ahead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As written in [Cloud Storage Connector installation documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/install-storage-connector), these properties should be specified in `conf/core-site.xml` file.

If you are configuring them directly through Spark (programmatically or adding them to `spark-defaults.conf`) then [you need to add](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#custom-hadoophive-configuration) `spark.hadoop.` prefix to [all of them](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigdata-interop/blob/master/gcs/INSTALL.md#configure-spark).

Comment: I am having similar issue even after setting below. spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile","path_to_file.json")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.impl", "com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.hadoop.google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable", "true")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.gs.project.id", "my-project-id")

Comment: If you are setting properties through `spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration`, then you don't need to add `spark.hadoop.` prefix to properties, because Spark already knows that this is Hadoop configuration.